# View the contents of 6 divs in just 2 divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to make the code below switch the content 1,2,3,4,5,6 within just two divs?
The current code only mix the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6. But what I need is that the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 and 6 are displayed randomly within just 2 divs.

Example:
2 and 6

press f5
4 and 1

press f5
5 and 3

How to do this ?

```css
* {
  font: 18pt verdana;
}
ul {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0 1px;
  width: 2.0em;
  border: 1px solid #006699;
}
li {
  margin: 1px 0;
  padding: 3px 0;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #006699;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type='text/javascript'>
    for (var $x = $(".content li"), i = $x.length - 1, j, temp; i >= 0; i--) {
      j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)), temp = $x[i], $x[i] = $x[j], $x[j] = temp;
    }
    $x.each(function(i, li) {
      $(".content").append(li);
    });
  </script>


</head>

<body>
  <div id="n"></div>
  <ul class="content">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you trying to append the `<li>` element to the `<ul>` element or `<div id="n"></div>` element?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/) to get just two elements from the mixed set, try this:

```
$(".content li").detach();
var y = $x.slice(0,2);
y.each(function(i, li) { $(".content").append(li); });
```

### [Updated Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fe7JL/175/)